# Namespace " Is not available to be referenced in this schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Hello I am very new to XML Schemas. (This is my first attempt.)
I can't understand why I keep getting this error.  Namespace " Is not available to be referenced in this schema.

This is the line i get the error on.

```
           <sch:element name="Field1" type="naming"/>
```

XSD FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/MySchemaFile"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <sch:element name="Root">
    <sch:complexType>
      <sch:sequence>
        <sch:element name="Nodes" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <sch:complexType>
            <sch:sequence>
              <sch:element name="Field1" type="naming"/>
              <sch:element name="Field2" type="sch:string"/>
              <sch:element name="Field3" type="sch:integer" default="0"/>
              <sch:element name="Field4" type="sch:string" default="0"/>
              <sch:element name="Field5" type="sch:string"/>
              <sch:element name="Field6" type="sch:string"/>
              <sch:element name="Field7" type="sch:string" default="0"/>
              <sch:element name="Field8" type="sch:string" default="0"/>
              <sch:element name="Field9" type="sch:string" default="None"/>
            </sch:sequence>
          </sch:complexType>
        </sch:element>
      </sch:sequence>
    </sch:complexType>
  </sch:element>

    <sch:simpleType name="naming">
      <sch:restriction base ="sch:string">
        <sch:minLength value="0"/>
        <sch:maxLength value="5"/>
      </sch:restriction>
    </sch:simpleType>

</sch:schema>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks to anyone that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have defined a target namespace, which means that all type definitions will live in this namespace. But your type reference for Field1 refers to the empty namespace. Declare an extra namespace:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/MySchemaFile"
           xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/MySchemaFile"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

and use that prefix when referring to types defined in your schema:

```
        <sch:sequence>
          <sch:element name="Field1" type="tns:naming"/>
          <sch:element name="Field2" type="sch:string"/>
          ...
        </sch:sequence>
```

Comment: So you have to use the extra namespace for all global elements ?

Comment: You can add ```xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MySchemaFile``` (without :tns) if you want to avoid using a prefix for your global types.