# How to use datetime2 type in XML SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server, xml-schema-collection

I'm trying to use SQL Server XML SCHEMA types like `datetime2` in collections and tables

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [XmlValuesSchemaCollection_datetime2] AS 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sql2008/SqlTypes.xsd"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="datetime2" type="xsd:datetime2"/>
</xsd:schema>';
GO

CREATE TABLE XmlValuesTable_datetime2 (
    [uid] [int] IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    v XML(XmlValuesSchemaCollection_datetime2) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO XmlValuesTable_datetime2 (v)  
VALUES (N'<datetime2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2014-06-18 06:39:05.190</datetime2>');
GO
```

but I have error `Reference to an undefined name 'datetime2' within namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'`. Same with `type="xsd:datetime2"` - error

```
Reference to an undefined name 'datetime2' within namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sql2008/SqlTypes.xsd'
```

It suppose to work somehow, types described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb677236(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN but unfortunately I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Have you seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138158/namespace-is-not-available-to-be-referenced-in-this-schema)?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and 2017. I'll read those thread (never seen before because was searching with Google and not sure how and what for namespaces used, in examples they mostly to microsoft.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erland Sommarskog answered at [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ba435a19-a843-4950-a155-4626982b17fc/how-to-use-new-types-like-datetime2-in-xml-schema?forum=sqlxml)
Solution is

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [XmlValuesSchemaCollection_datetime2] AS 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes"      attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sql2008/sqltypes.xsd"/>

   <xsd:element name="datetime2" type="sqltypes:datetime2"/>
</xsd:schema>';
```